# Calculate table rows and populate the grand total field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table like below :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Product Type</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
     <td>Gas</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="qty" /></td>
     <td>
        <select id="unit" name="unit">
           <option value="30.42">Liter</option>
           <option value="25.30">Ton</option>
           <option value="45.10">Kg</option>
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Diesel</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="qty" /></td>
     <td>
        <select id="unit" name="unit">
           <option value="20.42">Liter</option>
           <option value="18.30">Ton</option>
           <option value="25.10">Kg</option>
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Fuel</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="qty" /></td>
     <td>
        <select id="unit" name="unit">
           <option value="30.42">Liter</option>
           <option value="25.30">Ton</option>
           <option value="45.10">Kg</option>
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total" /></td>
  </tr>
```

I would like to calculate ( qty * unit ) each row based `qty` and `unit` and put the result `total` column.

At the end of the calculation, I want to `sum` whole `total` fields and put the Grand Total field.

I tried like below which is always returning `NaN` but when I checked the value by `typeof` returning `number`!!! :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('input[name^=qty], select[name^=unit]').change(function(){  
   var total = 0;
   var $row = $(this).parent();  
   var qty = parseFloat($row.find('input[name=qty]').val());  
   var price = parseFloat($row.find("select[name='unit'] option:selected").val());
   total = parseFloat(qty * price);  
   $row.find('.amount').text(parseFloat(qty * price));  
})  
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors here, including using `text()` on an input field, and using `parent()` instead of `closest("tr")`.

I've also added classes to your elements to make the selectors easier. Try this:

```
$('.qty, .unit').change(function(){  
   var total = 0;
   var $row = $(this).closest("tr");  
   var qty = parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val());  
   var price = parseFloat($row.find(".unit").val());
   total = parseFloat(qty * price);  
   $row.find('.total').val(parseFloat(qty * price));  
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ng2qF/)

---

**UPDATE**

Added blank default to selects:

```
$('.qty, .unit').change(function(){  
    var total = 0;
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");  
    var qty = parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val());  
    var price = parseFloat($row.find(".unit").val());
    total = qty * price;  

    if (isNaN(total)) {
        $row.find('.total').val("");  
    }
    else {
        $row.find('.total').val(total);  
    }
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ng2qF/1/)

Comment: Okies + 1 for using class bruv, Legend!

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible us the `option:selected` element in this snippet? Because, when user input a qty, the script automatically calculate based the default `option`.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir by using `.val()` on a select, jQuery automatically gets the value of the selected `option`. If you don't want that, add an empty option to each of your selects.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `var $row = $(this).parent();` try

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

The code you have is looking at the td and you need to find the tr.  Closest looks for the closest match up the DOM tree.

Comment: good lord thank you! for closest(), nothing to do with the question but I personnaly needed that function so much !

Answer (score 2):

Try this,not tested

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('input[name^=qty], select[name^=unit]').change(function(){  
   var total = 0;
   var $row = $(this).parent().prev();  //changed here
   var qty = parseFloat($row.find('input[name=qty]').val());  
   var price = parseFloat($row.find("select[name='unit'] option:selected").val());
   total = parseFloat(qty * price);  
   $row.find('.amount').text(parseFloat(qty * price));  
})  
});
```